# How can we make a process restart faster?

Tags: android, process

i have an app that runs a process and a service.

When I use an auto killer application, it ends the process of that app and then it shows "restarting.." when I see the running applications.

How can I make this "restart" faster or how can I prevent the auto killer apps from ending my process app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make this "restart" faster?

Follow good programming practices and design patterns that make your app more efficient and responsive

> How can I prevent the auto killer apps from ending my process app?

I think that this is **not** possible.

Comment: can you give me info about that?